# Configuring Sequoyah to debug JNI code

Tags: android, eclipse, java-native-interface, android-ndk

The only documentation I have found is

http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/documentation/native_debug.php

Following this, when I go to set the debugger in step 6, instead of a dropdown with gdbserver, I have an empty dropdown on the debug tab in the debugger field.

Answer (score 0):

I think I once had an issue similar to this, which I solved by uninstalling Sequoyah and CDT, then re-installing Sequoyah first (so it would pick up the correct CDT dependencies).

If you're still having trouble with NDK debugging (I know this question is quite old), you could take a look at the guide I wrote when I was setting it up. You can find it [here](http://esotericgamer.co.uk/pro/android-ndk.html).